# React js - How to select all rows ID from HTML table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to select all rows Id that contains in html table by one click i tried to do this but that function does not work and array list shows empty how to do that i can select all rows id by single checkbox and i want all rows id in `selectedItems` as list form . here is my code that i did.

```
this.state = {
      checkedBoxCheck: false,
     selectedItems: [],
stats: [],
}

 componentDidMount() {
    ...
  }



toggleSelectAll() {
    let selectedItems = [];

    if (this.state.selectAll === 0) {
      this.state.stats.forEach(x => {
        selectedItems[x.id] = true;
      });
    }
    this.setState({
      selectedItems: selectedItems,
      checkedBoxCheck: true
    });

    console.log(selectedItems);
  }


           <thead>
                <tr style={{ marginTop: "-88px" }}>
                  <th class="active" style={{ width: "20px" }}>
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      class="select-all checkbox"
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                      name="first_name"
                      onClick={this.toggleSelectAll.bind(this)}
                    />
                  </th>
                  <th className="" style={{ width: "20px" }}>
                    {t("Id")}
                  </th>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
                {stats.map((c, i) => (
                  <tr key={c.id}>
                    <td>
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        id="togBtn"
                        className="checkbox"
                        name="selectOptions"
                        onClick={() => this.onItemSelect(c.id)}
                      />
                    </td>
                    <td>{c.id}</td>
             </tbody>
```

Comment: Note - this is invalid HTML.  `id` must be unique, but you have created multiple `inputs` with `id="togBtn"`.

Comment: First of all, it isn't clear if you stats is not empty. Second, your selectedItems is an array, but you try to use it like an object. You need to convert it to object, and then you can do it like you do, or you need to change this code selectedItems[x.id] = true; to selectedItems.push(x.id), or selectedItems.push({[x.id]: true});